# react-navigation can't navigate between screens even after following react-navigation docs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am following [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html) doc from react-navigation to learn and I am trying and trying but I can't navigate between screens. Each time I change something a random error is popping up. App.js is running fine if I call just one screen as `<HomeScreen/>` inside the root of App.js.

I am calling HomeScreen like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import HomeScreen from './Comps/HomeScreen';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import DetailsScreen from './Comps/DetailsScreen';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HomeScreen />
    );
  }
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Now this is working fine, showing whats inside `HomeScreen.js`

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, Button } from 'react-native';
 import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
 import { createAppContainer, navigation } from 'react-navigation';
 import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

 class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
     render() {
       return (
         <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
           <Text>Home Screen</Text>
           <Button
             title="Go to Details"
             onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
           />
         </View>
       );
     }
   }

 export default HomeScreen;
```

but when I click on the button a random ***error*** pops up, sometimes it says undefined is not an object, sometimes it can't find `StackNavigator`, sometimes it has problems with navigation. I installed all the dependencies but still please tell me if I am missing something here.

From `HomeScreen.js` I am calling `DetailsScreen.js` like said in the doc.

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, Button } from 'react-native';
 import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
 import { createAppContainer, navigation } from 'react-navigation';
 import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
 import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';


 class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
     render() {
         return (
             <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                 <Text>Details Screen</Text>
                 <Button
                     title="Go to Details... again"
                     onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
                 />
             </View>
         );
     }
 }
 export default DetailsScreen;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define an AppContainer([What is AppContainers](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html)) using createAppContainer like this

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

and there RootStack  will be the list of screens that you want to show. add them like this using createStackNavigator([what is createStackNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html)) like this:

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Details: DetailsScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);
```

and add both the `const AppContainer` and `const RootStack` in App.js and then export the `class App` like this:

```
 export default class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return <AppContainer/>;
   }
```

If the screens are in different file, say `./Comps/HomeScreen.js` or `./Comps/DetailsScreen.js` then import them in App.js before creating the screens. like this:

```
import HomeScreen from './Comps/HomeScreen';
import DetailsScreen from './Comps/DetailsScreen'
```

Comment: perfectly explained. hope it helps